# The meaning of "line mattress and pillows if you are allergic to dust mites"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found the following sentence in this [link](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/can-get-sore-throat-sleeping-open-window/) and I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of it.

"Line mattress and pillows if you are allergic to dust mites"

What does it mean to line a mattress or a pillow? I have found two possible definitions in this context for the verb "line", but I don't think either one of them is the "exact" definition in this case:

1. To fit a covering to the inside surface of.
2. To cover the inner surface of.

(The inside or the inner surface of a matress or a pillow?)

Thank you!

Comment: It means a [**lining**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lining): *A layer of different material covering the inside surface of something.* Like a double layer, for example two pillow cases on one pillow. The 'inside' is the inside of the outer layer. Obviously, you can't put it inside the pillow itself.

Comment: I suspect that in this context it implies a tight covering that is inside the pillowcase or under the bottom sheet.

Comment: *Pillow liner* is a pretty common term. However, if you search for it on the Bed, Bath and Beyond website (an authoritative source, I submit), you get redirected to *pillow protector*. For example: https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/s/pillow-liners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To line a mattress and a pillow means to use a mattress protector and a pillow cover as the first layer followed by a top layer which is the bedsheet and the pillow case.  You can google the images of a mattress cover and a pillow cover.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!